# The procedure entry point mysql_get_option could not be located in the dll libmysql.dll

Tags: c++, mysql, dll

I am just using the example code from the mysql site.  This program will compile and run if I do it in debug.  If I compile in release it gives me the error in the title.  I downloaded all the connectors and server from oracle site, so everything is up to date on my end.  I even compiled both the latest releases of c++ connectors and c connectors.  I have done a lot of searches on this and tried what they said to do, but could not fix this.  My lib and dll files from what I have seen have the mysql_get_option function listed.  I made sure there are no stray dll or lib files on my computer.  I checked the system path variable to make sure it wasnt pointing in some random area.  I am using Vs2013.

Please help I have tried to fix this for a week and my brain is about to explode!!  Thank you for any advice.

P.S.
I program as a hobby so it is more than likely I am overlooking something trivial.

```
    /* Copyright 2008, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.

There are special exceptions to the terms and conditions of the GPL
as it is applied to this software. View the full text of the
exception in file EXCEPTIONS-CONNECTOR-C++ in the directory of this
software distribution.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
*/

/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
Include directly the different
headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
(and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World0000........ AS _message'..." << endl;

        try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("*****", "*****", "*****");
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        //con->setReadOnly(true);
        con->setSchema(*****);
        cout << "\nHere!";
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT eqdkp10_raid_attendees.raid_id, eqdkp10_raids.raid_value \
                                  FROM eqdkp10_raids LEFT JOIN eqdkp10_raid_attendees ON eqdkp10_raids.raid_id \
                                  = eqdkp10_raid_attendees.raid_id AND eqdkp10_raid_attendees.member_id=2");
        while(res->next()) {
            cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
            /* Access column data by alias or column name */
            cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
            cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
            /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
            cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

    }
    catch(sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled your post title and found this link: http://www.linuxtalks.net/mysql-community-server-5-7-4-m14-has-been-released/

If your search the page for **mysql_get_option** you will see they fixed this known bug.  If you're using VS2013 your library version might include this bug since the page refers to a release in 2014.

Comment: Thank you.  I overlooked that because it was linuxtalks.